# Exposition of Drinfeld's proof of function field Langlands for GL(2)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, langlands-conjectures

I know, or think I know, the vague outline of the proof: the Galois-to-automorphic direction is "classical," i.e. follows from converse theorems due to Grothendieck et al., and for the automorphic-to-Galois direction we pass to geometric Langlands and the theory of eigensheaves and build some class of objects whose $\ell$-adic cohomology contains for each eigensheaf an appropriate Galois representation. In this case, this should be the moduli space of rank $2$ shtukas, which are (approximately?) pairs of modifications $\mathcal E \hookrightarrow \mathcal E' \hookleftarrow \mathcal E''$ at one point each of our curve $X$ labeled $0$ and $\infty$, with an isomorphism between $\mathcal E''$ and the pullback by Frobenius of $\mathcal E$.

My understanding is that L. and V. Lafforgue's proofs of function field Langlands for more general groups follow the same general program via suitable generalizations of shtukas and resolutions of the resulting difficulties. I can find expositions of these proofs, as expected, but having had difficulty with them I thought it would make sense by starting with trying to understand Drinfeld's proof in the $\text{GL}(2)$ case. However I've been unable to find any explanations (in English, at least) of this proof, much to my surprise, other than Drinfeld's original (translated) "Proof of the global Langlands conjecture for $\text{GL}(2)$," which is more of a summary of the proof. Does anyone know of an exposition? (Ideally in English, but I'd take French if necessary.)